# Problems installing Ubuntu Server on an empty SSD

Tags: server, partitioning, system-installation, ssd

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 22.04 or 23.10, both crashing with the same problem. My hardware is an AMD Ryzen 5 7640U mini-PC with Lexar NVMe SSD. I'm booting from a USB drive with OS image.

Installer doesn't see the out-of-the box empty SSD. I used GParted Live and created GPT partition table on SSD. After about a minute of "installer is probing for block devices" the drive is visible to the installer. I'm selecting the option "use an entire disk". The 22.04 installer stops with "there was a problem examining storage devices", but allows for manual continue. Both installers crash at the next step of setting user credentials, while "destructive action" is performed on SSD.

I have dual boot configuration with Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 and 23.10 running fine on another SSD on this PC. Is there an easy solution to this problem? Do I have to partition the drive before installation?

---

I tried the nightly build of Ubuntu Server 24.04 and it stopped at "installer is probing for block devices" step with `Probing for devices to install to failed` error.

---

I took another SSD with Ubuntu already on it and installed Ubuntu Server 23.10 on top of it with no problem. It seems that there may be a hardware problem with the Lexar NVMe SSD.

Comment: Have you updated both UEFI & SSD firmware? Even new devices may need an update. Check version & vendors support page for most current version.